# AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer no frame shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, avfoundation

After a week of struggle, I decided to ask for help:

I've tried two approaches:

1. Simply enqueuing the sample (since this is a live stream, the frames are coming in periodically):

   ```
   - (void)drawSample:(CMSampleBufferRef)sample {

       CFArrayRef attachments = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sample, YES);
       CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = (CFMutableDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachments, 0);
       CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately, kCFBooleanTrue);

       if (CMSampleBufferIsValid(sample)) {
           NSLog(@"Valid sample: %@", sample);
       }
       else {
           NSLog(@"Invalid sample: %@", sample);
       }

       [self.videoLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sample];
       [self.videoLayer setNeedsDisplay];

       if (self.colorIndex > 255) {
           self.colorIndex = 0;
       }

       self.videoLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:self.colorIndex / 255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

       self.colorIndex += 1;
   }
   ```

With this approach, no frame is shown (I've added the background color change code for debugging purposes, that's working fine).

---

2. The second approach was to display the frames as if they were coming in from an unconstrained source (though still using the same live stream).

   ```
   - (void)drawSample:(CMSampleBufferRef)sample {

       CFArrayRef attachments = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sample, YES);
       CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = (CFMutableDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachments, 0);
       CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately, kCFBooleanTrue);


       if (CMSampleBufferIsValid(sample)) {
           NSLog(@"Valid sample");
       }
       else {
           NSLog(@"Invalid sample: %@", sample);
       }

       [self.videoLayer requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:self.dispatchQueue usingBlock: ^{
           while( [_videoLayer isReadyForMoreMediaData] )
           {
               if (CMSampleBufferIsValid(sample)) {
                   [_videoLayer enqueueSampleBuffer:sample];
                   CFRelease(sample);
               }
               else {
                   NSLog(@"Invalid sample inside block: %@", sample);
               }

           }
           NSLog(@"Layer isn't ready");
       }];
   }
   ```

The isn't working either. With this approach I have 2 problems:

- If I add `CFRelease(sample);` inside the block, the application will crash. With Zombie Objects enabled, I get the error message:

  ```
  [Not A Type release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fc6426a2120
  ```

  Should I be storing the CMSampleBufferRef objects in a container and retrieving the inside the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer's request media block?
- If I don't add the `CFRelease(sample);` inside the block, only the first frame will be shown and the application will eventually crash due to memory warning (obviously).

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

NOTE: I've watched the "Direct access to media encoding and decoding" video from the 2014 WWDC and I seem to be doing everything correctly. I've created the video format description, replaced the start code with the length code in the NAL units and created the CMSampleBuffer with success.

Comment: did u solved this? I have similar issue wher eI can see only the first frame :(

Comment: The project was shipped and working, so I must've fixed this issue. Though it was like 2 years ago, so I don't remember anything :(
I'll check if I still have the source code and see what I can do.